# How can I cite a reference in french ("et" instead of "and" between author names)?

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I'm currently writing my thesis, and I'm need to cite a reference using "et" instead of "and" between author names, for example:

> Copin-montégut et Avril (1995)

Comment: Try one of the bst files listed at ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/bib-fr]

Comment: Have a look at https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/francais-bst?lang=de

Comment: thank you for your comments, i have tried to use this package, but I am getting this error: ! Package babel Error: You haven't defined the language en yet.See the babel package documentation for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \select@language{en}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@BOOK{foo,
  AUTHOR =       {J. Doe and F. Foo},
  address =      {Paris},
  TITLE =        {Comment gagner au loto ?},
  PUBLISHER =    {Seuil},
  YEAR =         {2015},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
Voici ma citation : \citet{foo}.
\bibliographystyle{plainnat-fr}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

seems to give what was expected:

[image]