# Bibliography latex in french

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, french

I am using `\bibliographystyle{plainnatfr}` to generate references. For example,

```
@inproceedings{cohen2003inference,
  title={Inference of human postures by classification of 3D human body shape},
  author={Cohen, Isaac and Li, Hongxia},
  booktitle={Analysis and Modeling of Faces and Gestures, 2003. AMFG 2003. IEEE International Workshop on},
  pages={74--81},
  year={2003},
  organization={IEEE}
}
```

when I use `citep{cohen2003inference}`, it generates `Cohen and Li`. How can i get the french version `Cohen et Li` ?

Comment: Have you ever checked this?: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281380/how-can-i-cite-a-reference-in-french-et-instead-of-and-between-author-names

Comment: The name of the style is `plainnat-fr`. Here, when `plainnat-fr` is used with `natbib`, I get `Cohen et Li`. Can you give a MWE?

Answer (score 3):

With this package `\usepackage[french,english]{babel}` and before the `\printbibliography` you can use `\selectlanguage{french}` to obtain it.

**EDIT**

As indicated in comments, it is before the `\bibliography{file}` instead of `\printbibliography`

Comment: The question contains `\bibliographystyle` so `biblatex` is not in use

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: Then, please, provide a MWE example that we can fully help you. Have you also try with the dash like that `plainnat-fr`? See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281380/how-can-i-cite-a-reference-in-french-et-instead-of-and-between-author-names to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Some guy explains it all there : [There](https://www.irit.fr/~Alain.Crouzil/jaffre/LOGICIELS/LATEX_BIBTEX/bibtex1.html)